# arbitrary method names in javascript object

Tags: javascript, function, object, arguments

I'm learning more about javascript OOP by rolling my own console.log variant with some extra features I want.

So far I have

```
debug = {
        consoleAvailable :  (typeof console == "object"),
        reportToConsole : 0,
        list            : [],
        setReporting    : function(level){
                            this.reportToConsole = level;
                            return true;
                        },
        log             : function(){
                            if (this.reportToConsole>0 && this.consoleAvailable && typeof console.log=="function")  console.log.apply(console, this.log.arguments);
                            this.list.push({'type':'log', 'msg':this.log.arguments});
                            return true;
                        },
};
```

This is all working nicely, but I don't want to have to list all of the log,error,warning etc functions. Instead I would like to be able to just type debug.[something] and for a function to interpret that [something] and execute it in the same way as I have the log function working.

Is this even possible? If so how do I go about it?

Here is some examples of what I would like to be able to do.

```
debug.setReporting(1); //yes, I want to print to console

debug.log('foo', 'bar', 'baz'); //arbitrary number of arguments (this is already working)
debug.error('qux'); //function I haven't named, but there is a console.error function
debug.arbitraryName([1, 2, 3]); //no function for console.arbitraryName (ideally it would just console.log the argument(s)
```

**Edit**

Ok, it looks like @Rob W's method is the way to go, however I am having trouble implementing. It seems that I am not passing the name of the function correctly or similar. I have a fiddle here showing the problem http://jsfiddle.net/xiphiaz/mxF4m/

**Conclusion**

It looks like there is too many browser quirks to get a truly generic debugger without writing browser specific code, so instead I have just listed my most used log functions (log, warning and error). This does give me the option to further customize result of each of these functions.

result:

```
debug = {
    consoleAvailable :  (typeof console == "object"),
    reportToConsole : 0,
    list            : [],
    setReporting    : function(level){
                        this.reportToConsole = level;
                        return true;
                    },
    log             : function(){
                        if (this.reportToConsole>0 && this.consoleAvailable && typeof console.log=="function")  console.log.apply(console, this.log.arguments);
                        this.list.push({type:'log', msg:this.log.arguments});
                        return true;
                    },
    warn            : function(){
                        if (this.reportToConsole>0 && this.consoleAvailable && typeof console.warn=="function") console.warn.apply(console, this.warn.arguments);
                        this.list.push({type:'warn', msg:this.warn.arguments});
                        return true;
                    },
    error           : function(){
                        if (this.reportToConsole>0 && this.consoleAvailable && typeof console.error=="function")    console.error.apply(console, this.error.arguments);
                        this.list.push({type:'error', msg:this.error.arguments});
                        return true;
                    }
};

debug.setReporting(1);

debug.log('foo', 'bar', 'baz');
debug.error('qux');
debug.warn({test:"warning"});
console.log(debug.list);
```

Comment: Note that in IE things like console.log are not a Functions, and therefore do not have an `apply` method for passing a variable amount of arguments. You would have to hard code the separate calls for various lengths: `a = arguments; if(a.length == 1){ console.log(a[0])} if(arguments.length == 2){ console.log(a[0], a[1]}`

Comment: But I am doing a check whether it is a function or not before attempting to `apply`. Is this not enough?

Comment: You should iterate over `console`, not over `console.__proto__`. See http://jsfiddle.net/mxF4m/1/

Comment: @Pumbaa80 I think this must be a browser specific thing again, as I tested this in Safari, and I get an error, but it works in Firefox...

Comment: Ah right. Firefox's console object is somehow special. It gets injected into `window` when you open the console panel, and is just a plain object containing some methods. Not sure about Safari's console implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get an array of all properties (including non-enumerable ones) using the [`Object.getOwnProprtyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) method. Then, enumerate through it, and check whether the `console[key]` is a function. If yes, extend your own object with the method.

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(console)
```

As for your last quesion, there's a non-standard [`__noSuchMethod__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/NoSuchMethod) method which intercepts calls to undefined functions.

I strongly recommend to use my first proposed method, because the `console` method will not magically grow bigger. It also makes debugging easier.

Comment: The problem with this is that I want the function to execute regardless of whether the property function exists (the function needs to add the arguments to the dialog.list array). I only want to know if the console.functions exists so I can call it without getting an error.

Comment: Sorry, I misread. The `__noSuchMethod__` appears to be what I was after, but its a real bummer that it isn't standard. Kinda defeats the purpose of making a cross-browser logger :(

Comment: @ZakHenry I understand your intentions. My first solution is the neatest possible method to accomplish this. It detects every existing `console.*` method, which can be added to your namespace. There is no universal getter method.

Comment: @ZakHenry: `__noSuchMethod__` is evil though. Why not be more clear and pass stuff explicitly as strings, as in `debug( 'arbitraryName', 1, 2)` ?

Comment: @missingno Yea I'm not going to use the `__noSuchMethod__`. I'm trying to make the syntax as simple as possible, but yea that method could work